# Angularjs factory class object has no method save

Tags: angularjs

im having a factory class as defined below

```
angular.module('App')
    .factory('Session', function($resource) {
 return {
    Sessionlogin : function() {
      return $resource('/api/session/');
    },

     Sessioncheckcredentails : function() {
      return $resource('/api/session/forgotusername');
    }

   }});
```

now im calling the function in controller as

```
login: function(user, callback) {
        var cb = callback || angular.noop;

        return Session.Sessionlogin.save({
          email: user.email,
          password: user.password,
          practicename: user.practicename          
        }, function(user) {
          $rootScope.currentUser = user;
          return cb();
        }, function(err) {
          return cb(err);
        }).$promise;
      }, with proper injection and all.,
```

> but im gettin error objection function().. has no method save..

I tried to include save:post in $resource but was in vain.

Comment: You need `Session.Sessionlogin().save`

Comment: What's the error now?

Comment: cheers mate! <need some more letters to submit comment>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        .factory('Session', function($resource) {
            var resource = $resource(url, { id: '@id' }, defaultOptions);

            return {
                add: function(param) {
                    return resource.save(param, function() {
                        onSuccessfullySaved();
                    }, function (errorResult) {
                        console.log(errorResult);
                    });
                }
```